# How i can resolve migration issue if migration file does not exist but entry available in migration table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I'm currently working with Laravel in a team, and lastly, I have created a migration to change table name from 'slide' to 'slides' and also executed migration on the local environment till this point everything is good. But when I switched to master branch and created a new feature branch then migration related to 'slides' table not available now but entry is available in migrations table and getting error like the following.

> include(/home/in-techouse/Projects/qidigo/qidigo/vendor/composer/../../database/migrations/2020_12_21_123136_alter_table_name_slide_to_slides.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

What will be the best way to handle this issue?

Comment: what is you migration class name?

Comment: Sounds like you’ve not merged your changes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you merged your branch in the master? You can see the file with `ls database/migrations`?

Try run `composer dump-autoload`